# Sorting random numbers into bins - C

Tags: c, sorting, if-statement, for-loop, random

I'm trying to write some code that sorts a generated random number, between 0 and 1, and sorts it into a 'bin', which is an array. The window then prints out saying the number of random numbers in each bin. Hope this makes some sense, but I'm really struggling. I'm a complete beginner, and I'm completely stuck, and need some help on how to make the code work and where to go next. Here's what I've got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
        {
        double x,y;
        int i;
        int data[i];
        unsigned int time_ui;
        time_ui = (unsigned int)( time(NULL) );
        srand(time_ui);
        x = rand()/ (double)RAND_MAX;
            data[i]=0;
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            (x*10)=y;
            if ((int)y == i)
            {
            data[i]+=1;
            }
        printf("Bin %d contains %d random numbers\n", i, data[i]);
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Andrew_CS my code doesn't work, I'm completely stuck with where to go next

Comment: What part is not working?  Are you getting an error?  If so please provide it.

Comment: What is `(x*10)=y;` supposed to do?  That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: The line `(x*10)=y;` is never going to work.  Expressions go to the right of the assignment (=), variable to be assigned the result goes to the left.

Comment: @Andrew_CS when it gets to the part that Carl is referring to.

Comment: `int i; int data[i];` is pretty terrible too; maybe you need to go back to basics?

Comment: @pjs ah that makes sense, I tried something the other day in a different bit of code that worked kind of like this and it worked, but it already had assigned values, thanks.

Comment: @CarlNorum I am at complete basics, it's an assignment in my first week of programming course at uni

Comment: Maybe you should ask your teacher for help then?

Comment: @CarlNorum it's a summer assignment from a lecturer we don't have yet, who I don't have contact details for. I wouldn't be asking on here if I didn't need help. Please stop being patronising and just help me out?

Comment: Unfortunately the help you're looking for is too broad for a simple answer and is therefore beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.  You're asking us to completely rewrite your program.  Please narrow down your question to something specific and re-ask.

Comment: They're giving you arrays for your first assignment? Yikes! @CarlNorum isn't being patronizing, he's giving good advice. Don't assume the worst of people.

Comment: @CarlNorum okay, that is more useful. So is there any chance you could give me some advice on what to learn about before I retry this?

Comment: Learn about basic assignment statements, learn about declaring and accessing arrays.

Comment: @pjs none of the students have any programming experience, and they've chucked us in at, although in reality it isn't, what feels like the deep end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I understood what you were trying to do, here is what I could come with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    double x,y;
    int i;
    int data[10];  // you will generate 10 bins
    unsigned int time_ui;
    time_ui = (unsigned int)( time(NULL) );
    srand(time_ui);


    for (i =0; i<10; i++) // initialize each bin
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i=0; i<100; i++)  // generate and examine 100 random you can do it for more
    {
        x = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX; // generate random number
        y = 10 *x;                   // predict in which bin it will be
        data[(int)y]++;              // increase that bin by 1
    }



    for (i =0; i<10; i++) // once done, let's print it out
    {
        printf("Bin %d contains %d random numbers\n", i, data[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**EDIT**

Not really important, just for fun you can print out results like that :

```
for (i =0; i<10; i++) // once done, let's print it out
    {
        printf("\t");
        for(j = 0; j<data[i]; j++)
        {
            printf("_ ");
        }
        printf("\nBin %d\t", i);
        for(j = 0; j<data[i]; j++)
        {
            printf("_|");
        }
        printf("%d\n", data[i]);

    }
```

Don't forget to define `int j;`

Comment: @alexheslop1 : Never mind , we are here to help each other